# Eventlet - ImportError: No module named dnskeybase

Tags: python, eventlet

I can't import eventlet on my production system. It's saying no module named dnskeybase.

```
# python scraper.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraper.py", line 7, in <module>
    import eventlet
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from eventlet import convenience
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/convenience.py", line 7, in <module>
    from eventlet.green import socket
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/green/socket.py", line 21, in <module>
    from eventlet.support import greendns
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/support/greendns.py", line 67, in <module>
    setattr(dns.rdtypes, pkg, import_patched('dns.rdtypes.' + pkg))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/support/greendns.py", line 59, in import_patched
    return patcher.import_patched(module_name, **modules)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/patcher.py", line 120, in import_patched
    *additional_modules + tuple(kw_additional_modules.items()))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/patcher.py", line 94, in inject
    module = __import__(module_name, {}, {}, module_name.split('.')[:-1])
ImportError: No module named dnskeybase
```

So I tried to install it...

```
# pip install dnskeybase
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Collecting dnskeybase
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dnskeybase (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for dnskeybase
```

and:

```
# pip install dnspython
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Requirement already satisfied: dnspython in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (1.16.0)
```

and the eventlet version/installation:

```
# pip install eventlet
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Collecting eventlet
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/86/7e/96e1412f96eeb2f2eca9342dcc4d5bc9305880a448b603b0a8e54439b71c/eventlet-0.24.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: monotonic>=1.4 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from eventlet) (1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from eventlet) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: dnspython>=1.15.0 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from eventlet) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: greenlet>=0.3 in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages (from eventlet) (0.4.15)
Requirement already satisfied: enum34; python_version < "3.4" in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from eventlet) (1.1.6)
Installing collected packages: eventlet
Successfully installed eventlet-0.24.1
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

Your local `dnspython` package installation is broken, or being masked by an incomplete `dns.rdtypes` package in a different location. It is missing (at least) the `dns.rdtypes.dnskeybase` module; it's just another [pure-Python module](https://github.com/rthalley/dnspython/blob/master/dns/rdtypes/dnskeybase.py), nothing special.

The exception message may look a little confusing, because it doesn't name the full path. The moral equivalent of the following Python expression is being executed:

```
module_name = 'dns.rdtypes.dnskeybase'
__import__(module_name, {}, {}, module_name.split('.')[:-1])
```

which uses the [`__import__` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) to dynamically import the `dnskeybase` module from the `dns.rdtypes` package. When it is missing, however, the `ImportError: No module named dnskeybase` exception raised doesn't include the `dns.rdtypes` component, even though that's the only location that the import was attempted from. The `eventlet.support.greendns` module has, by this stage, already imported `dns.rdtypes` itself, so we know that for your installation, that package at least is present and importable.

A normal full install of the package adds a `site-packages/dns` directory with the following files (plus corresponding `.pyc` byte-cache files):

```
lib/python2.7/site-packages/dns
├── __init__.py
├── _compat.py
├── dnssec.py
├── e164.py
├── edns.py
├── entropy.py
├── exception.py
├── flags.py
├── grange.py
├── hash.py
├── inet.py
├── ipv4.py
├── ipv6.py
├── message.py
├── name.py
├── namedict.py
├── node.py
├── opcode.py
├── py.typed
├── query.py
├── rcode.py
├── rdata.py
├── rdataclass.py
├── rdataset.py
├── rdatatype.py
├── rdtypes
│   ├── ANY
│   │   ├── AFSDB.py
│   │   ├── AVC.py
│   │   ├── CAA.py
│   │   ├── CDNSKEY.py
│   │   ├── CDS.py
│   │   ├── CERT.py
│   │   ├── CNAME.py
│   │   ├── CSYNC.py
│   │   ├── DLV.py
│   │   ├── DNAME.py
│   │   ├── DNSKEY.py
│   │   ├── DS.py
│   │   ├── EUI48.py
│   │   ├── EUI64.py
│   │   ├── GPOS.py
│   │   ├── HINFO.py
│   │   ├── HIP.py
│   │   ├── ISDN.py
│   │   ├── LOC.py
│   │   ├── MX.py
│   │   ├── NS.py
│   │   ├── NSEC.py
│   │   ├── NSEC3.py
│   │   ├── NSEC3PARAM.py
│   │   ├── OPENPGPKEY.py
│   │   ├── PTR.py
│   │   ├── RP.py
│   │   ├── RRSIG.py
│   │   ├── RT.py
│   │   ├── SOA.py
│   │   ├── SPF.py
│   │   ├── SSHFP.py
│   │   ├── TLSA.py
│   │   ├── TXT.py
│   │   ├── URI.py
│   │   ├── X25.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── CH
│   │   ├── A.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── IN
│   │   ├── A.py
│   │   ├── AAAA.py
│   │   ├── APL.py
│   │   ├── DHCID.py
│   │   ├── IPSECKEY.py
│   │   ├── KX.py
│   │   ├── NAPTR.py
│   │   ├── NSAP.py
│   │   ├── NSAP_PTR.py
│   │   ├── PX.py
│   │   ├── SRV.py
│   │   ├── WKS.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── dnskeybase.py
│   ├── dsbase.py
│   ├── euibase.py
│   ├── mxbase.py
│   ├── nsbase.py
│   └── txtbase.py
├── renderer.py
├── resolver.py
├── reversename.py
├── rrset.py
├── set.py
├── tokenizer.py
├── tsig.py
├── tsigkeyring.py
├── ttl.py
├── update.py
├── version.py
├── wiredata.py
└── zone.py
```

A properly installed `dnspython` version 1.16.0 produces the following MD5 checksum for the Python source files in the file tree:

```
$ ( cd /lib/python2.7/site-packages/dns; export LC_ALL=C; find . -name \*.py -exec md5sum {} \; | sort -k 2 | md5sum )
28e20d8474f4f07287c305dbd5dae8b8  -
```

If you run the same command and you get a different output then your local installation is incomplete.

I recommend you *reinstall* the package; this is trivially done with `pip install --ignore-installed`:

```
$ pip install --ignore-installed dnspython
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Collecting dnspython
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ec/d3/3aa0e7213ef72b8585747aa0e271a9523e713813b9a20177ebe1e939deb0/dnspython-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: dnspython
Successfully installed dnspython-1.16.0
```

If you still experience issues even after reinstalling, or you got the same MD5 checksum of the file tree, then you have a *different* `dns.rdtypes` package on your python module search path that is masking the proper version.

You can find that package by adding:

```
import dns.rdtypes
print(dns.rdtypes.__file__)
```

at the top of your `scraper.py` script, before the `import eventlet` line. Feel free to use `import sys; sys.exit()` right after to prevent the full traceback. The file printed should tell you where to look for the rogue package that is interfering. Once you find it, rename that `dns` directory, or adjust your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to not include the directory that the `dns` directory is located in, or delete it entirely.